# Generating route without spaces

Tags: php, mod-rewrite, symfony, routes

in my blog i set the route with the title of post

```
route:
    pattern:  /blog/{id}/{title}
    defaults: { _controller: AcmeBlogBundle:Blog:show }
```

if my title's blog is:

```
"Hello World"
```

my route is www.mysite.com/5/Hello World    (with space)
but i want remove spaces, and use _   like

```
Hello_World
```

and i have another question
if my title is:

`" l'ancora"` how i can remove ' ?
thx

i have to add some rules in mod rewrite?
RewriteRule ^blog/([^_]*)*([^*]*?)\d*.php$ blog/$1-$2 [R=301,L]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case, the best is to use the [Sluggable DoctrineExtension](https://github.com/l3pp4rd/DoctrineExtensions/blob/master/doc/sluggable.md).

And some tips here : [How to use Doctrine Extension](http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/cookbook/doctrine/common_extensions.html)

Comment: You can try, but it is definitely not the proper way to do it. With sluggable extension, it take care of all undesired characters in your url (space, apostrophes, accents, etc...). And many other things !